# Is there a way to back-up a (free) excite email account?

Tags: email, backup

I've got an old excite email account that I've had for the last decade and change.  It's mostly a spam trap now, but I've got a lot of old emails from the mid-late 90s I'd like to keep.

The whole excite system is getting steadily sketchier, so I'd like to pull all my stuff out of there and back it up somewhere (my gmail account, on my hard drive, anywhere really.)

The problem is that excite only allows access to the POP3 servers with a paid account.  I could just drop the 25 bucks and upgrade for the length of time it would take to download everything, but I'd just as well not.

Does anyone know a way to pull email out of excite for free, or do I need to just pull out my credit card?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [FreePOPs](http://www.freepops.org/en/). Supposedly this also works with excite and it will let you use a normal, local email client to retrieve messages.